# Why does IE flag telerik.common.min.js as faulty, should I care, and if so, what should I do about it?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, telerik, internet-explorer-10, google-chrome-devtools

Running my asp.net app in IE, it fails on this line in telerik.common.min.js:

```
var aA=parseInt(a.browser.version.substring(0,5).replace(".",""))
```

saying, "*SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference 
telerik.common.min.js*"

Chrome took no such issues with the telerik js file.

A similar error takes place with this line:

```
b.scripts.push("telerik.menu.js")
```

As IE says, "*SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'scripts' of undefined or null reference*"

Is telerik's js code really bad in these instances, or is IE being overly wary?

IOW: Should I ignore these err msgs and just click through them, or...???

Comment: I've done several projects with Telerik's Sitefinity (which includes radcontrols), and it really is bad. If your doing anything that injects telerik provided CSS good luck, they use `!important` as a standard practice. What product of theirs are you using thats throwing this error? I might have some more specific insight.

Comment: We use a whole slew of telerik components; I don't know which part of their offerings is causing this. I had to install a gazillion things, but what exactly (telerik-wise) this humongous project is using, I don't know. I have to admit, one of my coworkers does call them "terrible telerik."

Comment: It looks like your probably using the radmenu control they provide for navigation? Do you have any sort of link that can be viewed? I understand the errors, but im not sure what is coming before it that would cause `b` to not point to `head` or `body` as im sure they want it to do.

Comment: to me it looks like you're using a newer version of jQuery that doesn't support `$.browser`. Try including jQuery 1.7.2 or the jQuery migrate plugin.

Comment: @Kevin B: Yes, I'm using jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: @ericjbasti: No link, sorry; this is a site for customers.

Comment: @ericjbasti: With Chrome and Firefox there are no such errors.

Comment: Are you overriding the jQuery Telerik wants to load? The code they write is very dependent on things like that not changing.

Comment: I typically have to load 2 versions of jQuery if I really need a new feature, and just apply .noConflict(); . Not an ideal solution but eventually you get tired of trying to reverse what they've done.

Comment: I'm not aware of what Telerik tries to do; I've got my own jQuery/jQueryUI references.

Comment: Check this document it will probably explain what they're expecting. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html

Comment: @ericjbasti: Thanks; I don't know what telerik gives us, really; I'm using jQuery UI components and other plugins, but not their widgets...I was just told that installing the Telerik stuff was necessary, but was not directed to use their widgets, or even advised they had such - I only see that now, on looking at the link you provided.

Comment: @ClayShannon try including the jQuery migrate plugin after jQuery 1.9.1. Does the error go away? (this is a debugging tool, not a final solution)

Comment: @Kevin B: Already have migrate included (in several places, actually).